# LSTM-RNN: num_classes usage

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using LSTM RNN to detect whether a heart beat is arrhythmic or not. So the output classes are:[0,1] and n_classes=2, but when this code is executed:

```
 # Fit training using batch data
_, loss, acc = sess.run(
    [optimizer, cost, accuracy],
    feed_dict={
        x: batch_xs, 
        y: batch_ys
    }
)
```

It gives following error

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'

Here is the whole code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf  # Version 1.0.0 (some previous versions are used in past commits)
from sklearn import metrics
import _pickle as cPickle
import os
import pandas as pd

import functions as f
[ml2_train_input,ml2_train_output,ml2_train_peaks,ml2_test_input,ml2_test_output,ml2_test_peaks]=f.get_ml2(0.5)
ml2_train_output=f.get_binary_output(ml2_train_output[:52500])
ml2_test_output=f.get_binary_output(ml2_test_output[:52500])


# Output classes to learn how to classify
LABELS = [0,1 ]             

training_data_count = len(ml2_train_input[:52500])  # training series 
test_data_count = len(ml2_test_input[:52500])  # testing series
n_input = 360  # 360 input parameters per timestep


# LSTM Neural Network's internal structure

n_hidden = 8 # Hidden layer num of features
n_classes = 2 # Total classes 

# Training 

learning_rate = 0.005
lambda_loss_amount = 0.0015
training_iters = training_data_count * 10  # Loop 10 times on the dataset
batch_size = 500
display_iter = 1000  # To show test set accuracy during training
X_test=np.array(ml2_test_input[:52500])
y_test=np.array(ml2_test_output[:52500])
# Some debugging info

print("Some useful info to get an insight on dataset's shape and normalisation:")
print("(X shape, y shape, every X's mean, every X's standard deviation)")
print(X_test.shape, y_test.shape, np.mean(X_test), np.std(X_test))
print("The dataset is therefore properly normalised, as expected, but not yet one-hot encoded.")

def LSTM_RNN(_X, _weights, _biases):
    # Function returns a tensorflow LSTM (RNN) artificial neural network from given parameters. 
    # Moreover, two LSTM cells are stacked which adds deepness to the neural network. 
    # Note, some code of this notebook is inspired from an slightly different 
    # RNN architecture used on another dataset, some of the credits goes to 
    # "aymericdamien" under the MIT license.

    # (NOTE: This step could be greatly optimised by shaping the dataset once
    # input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
      # permute n_steps and batch_size
    # Reshape to prepare input to hidden activation
    #_X = tf.reshape(_X, [-1, n_input]) 
    # new shape: (n_steps*batch_size, n_input)

    # Linear activation
    _X = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(_X, _weights['hidden']) + _biases['hidden'])
    # Split data because rnn cell needs a list of inputs for the RNN inner loop
    _X = tf.split(_X, 500,0) 
    # new shape: n_steps * (batch_size, n_hidden)

    # Define two stacked LSTM cells (two recurrent layers deep) with tensorflow
    lstm_cell_1 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True,reuse=None)
    lstm_cell_2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True,reuse=None)
    lstm_cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell_1, lstm_cell_2], state_is_tuple=True)
    # Get LSTM cell output
    outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cells, _X, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Get last time step's output feature for a "many to one" style classifier, 
    # as in the image describing RNNs at the top of this page
    lstm_last_output = outputs[-1]

    # Linear activation
    return tf.matmul(lstm_last_output, _weights['out']) + _biases['out']


def extract_batch_size(_train, step, batch_size):
    # Function to fetch a "batch_size" amount of data from "(X|y)_train" data. 

    shape = list(_train.shape)
    shape[0] = batch_size
    batch_s = np.empty(shape)

    for i in range(batch_size):
        # Loop index
        index = ((step-1)*batch_size + i) % len(_train)
        batch_s[i] = _train[index] 

    return batch_s


def one_hot(y_):
    # Function to encode output labels from number indexes 
    # e.g.: [[5], [0], [3]] --> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]

    y_ = y_.reshape(len(y_))
    n_values = int(np.max(y_)) + 1
    return np.eye(n_values)[np.array(y_, dtype=np.int32)]  # Returns FLOATS

# Graph input/output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

# Graph weights
weights = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden])), # Hidden layer weights
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes], mean=1.0))
}
biases = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

pred = LSTM_RNN(x, weights, biases)

# Loss, optimizer and evaluation
l2 = lambda_loss_amount * sum(
    tf.nn.l2_loss(tf_var) for tf_var in tf.trainable_variables()
) # L2 loss prevents this overkill neural network to overfit the data

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=pred)) + l2 # Softmax loss
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost) # Adam Optimizer

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# To keep track of training's performance
test_losses = []
test_accuracies = []
train_losses = []
train_accuracies = []

# Launch the graph
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
X_train=np.array(ml2_train_input[:52500])
y_train=np.array(ml2_train_output[:52500])
step = 1
while step * batch_size <= training_iters:
    batch_xs =         extract_batch_size(X_train, step, batch_size)
    batch_ys = one_hot(extract_batch_size(y_train, step, batch_size))

    # Fit training using batch data
    _, loss, acc = sess.run(
        [optimizer, cost, accuracy],
        feed_dict={
            x: batch_xs, 
            y: batch_ys
        }
    )
    train_losses.append(loss)
    train_accuracies.append(acc)

    # Evaluate network only at some steps for faster training: 
    if (step*batch_size % display_iter == 0) or (step == 1) or (step * batch_size > training_iters):

        # To not spam console, show training accuracy/loss in this "if"
        print("Training iter #" + str(step*batch_size) + \
              ":   Batch Loss = " + "{:.6f}".format(loss) + \
              ", Accuracy = {}".format(acc))

        # Evaluation on the test set (no learning made here - just evaluation for diagnosis)
        loss, acc = sess.run(
            [cost, accuracy], 
            feed_dict={
                x: X_test,
                y: one_hot(y_test)
            }
        )
        test_losses.append(loss)
        test_accuracies.append(acc)
        print("PERFORMANCE ON TEST SET: " + \
              "Batch Loss = {}".format(loss) + \
              ", Accuracy = {}".format(acc))

    step += 1

print("Optimization Finished!")
```

Please help!

Comment: change `n_classes` to 1

Comment: I thought of doing so, but there we do mention no. of classes right? @RickyHan

Comment: You are right. Don't change the total number classes. Just change `y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])` to `y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])`

Comment: Ok, I am trying this @RickyHan

Comment: It didn't work @RickyHan

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should convert your Y values to categorical (one-hot encoded) than it should work. So try to convert your Y values to categorical

Comment: You should consider providing a code example how this conversion can be archived. As a side note, this is an old question.